# Suck on proving factoring part of Euclid's GCD problem

Tags: proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to understand why Elucid's GCD algorithm works given two integers $a$ and $b$

$$
gcd(a,b) = gcd(q \cdot b +r, b)\\\
q = \frac{a}{b}  \;\; \text{where q is the quotient} \\
r = a \bmod b  \;\; \text{where r is the remainder} \\
x = \text{is a common factor between a and b} \\
x \shortmid  a  \; \& \Rightarrow x \shortmid (q \cdot b) \; \&  \; x \shortmid r
$$ 
I know for sure that x divides  $(q \cdot b)$ because q is an integer scalar, but how can I prove that x must also be a factor of r? I believe that this is the critical part of the proof that I can't understand.

I am following along this video of the proof on [youtube](https://youtu.be/jyKZSdKCS3M?t=6m27s) if you need to reference that specific part that I am stuck on.

Comment: I like your pun in the title: *Suck on proving...* instead of saying *Stuck on proving...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ divides *both* $a$ and $b$ (and hence also divides $\gcd(a,b)$), then it also divides $a-b$, $a-2b$, $a-3b$, and so on, all the way to $r=a-qb$, which means $x$ divides $\gcd(r,b)$.

If $x$ divides both $r$ and $b$, i.e. $x$ divides $\gcd(r,b)$, then it also divides $a=r+qb$.

So any number that divides $\gcd(a,b)$ also divides $\gcd(r,b)$, and vice versa, which (because $\gcd$'s are positive) means we must have $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(r,b)$.